I can't get sessionID through Middleware with the new Clerk
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


const isPrivateRoute = createRouteMatcher([
  '/dashboard(.*)',
]);
const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher([
  '/(.*)',
  '/auth/sign-in(.*)',
  '/auth/sign-up(.*)'

])
export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  if(isPrivateRoute(req)){
      if(!auth().sessionId && !auth().userId){
        auth().protect();
      }
    return NextResponse.next(); 
  }
  
  return NextResponse.next();
},{ debug:true});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

I'm building a SaaS and I'm using Clerk to do user authentication. I use Middleware to check the logged in user's sessionID to provide a private route. Even after the user is logged in, the middleware cannot get the sessionID and redirects, according to auth().protect().
